# Mount/Use LUKS .img file with Header and Key file

Tags: encryption, luks

This is for a cybersecurity school challenge.
I need to get into a .img file that was encrypted using LUKS. They have provided a header file and a key file to open it as well.

I am brand new to Linux systems and I am having trouble understanding the articles on this subject.

The command:
**sudo cryptsetup luksOpen** <image_name.img> **--header** <Header_File_name> **--master-key-file** <Key_file_name>

...Is saying Command requires device and mapped name as arguements.

From what I understand so far: since I have a header file on its own that is called a detached header so it uses the --header command and the --master-key-file is used for the key.

If looking at the actual files helps I put them in google drive here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QDq0DeNFHm6he9mPfMzdPOIYQfeUAEg7?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Cryptsetup doesn't transform the locked volume "in place" – it creates a *new* virtual device through which the unencrypted data can be read. For example, if you had an encrypted /dev/sda3 and tried to luksOpen it, you'd get a new device such as /dev/mapper/system that you're then supposed to use, while the original /dev/sda3 would still appear to be encrypted the whole time.

In your command, you only specified the "device" to open (I'm not sure if cryptsetup can directly accept regular files in place of devices) – but you haven't provided the name of the unlocked virtual device to create. Add a parameter like "myimage" in order to get /dev/mapper/myimage (the actual name is your choice).

This is independent from needing to specify the header-file or master-key parameters in your situation.